# Select box not changing while dynamically adding rows in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi iam able to add rows dynamically from the table below using javascript but the onchange function fired on the select box only works on the first row added how do you make it work for every row being added.Thanks.

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src='script.js'></script>  
        <table id="addProducts" border="1">
            <tr>
                <td>POI</td>
                <td>Quantity</td>
                <td>Price</td>
                <td>Product</td>
                <td>Add Rows?</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td><input size=25 type="text" id="lngbox" readonly=true/></td> 
                <td><input size=25 type="text" id="price" readonly=true/></td>
                <td>
                    <select name="selRow0" class="products">
                        <option value="value0">Product 1</option>
                        <option value="value1">Product 2</option>
                    </select>   
                </td>   
                <td><input type="button" id="delProducts" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"/></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="addmoreProducts" value="AddMore" onclick="insRow()"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div id="shw"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

```js
$(function () {
    $("select.products").on("change", function () {
        var selected = $(this).val();
        $("#price").val(selected);
    })
});


function deleteRow(row)
{
    var i = row.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
    document.getElementById('addProducts').deleteRow(i);
}


function insRow()
{
    var x = document.getElementById('addProducts');
    // deep clone the targeted row
    var new_row = x.rows[1].cloneNode(true);
    // get the total number of rows
    var len = x.rows.length;
    // set the innerHTML of the first row 
    new_row.cells[0].innerHTML = len;

    // grab the input from the first cell and update its ID and value
    var inp1 = new_row.cells[1].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    inp1.id += len;
    inp1.value = '';

    // grab the input from the first cell and update its ID and value
    var inp2 = new_row.cells[2].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    inp2.id += len;
    inp2.value = '';

    // append the new row to the table
    x.appendChild(new_row);
}
```

Comment: Try `$(document).on('change', 'select.products', function(){});`.

Comment: Not working.though..Thanks Huelfe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've updated your code. This should work now. Look at [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jg1rum0t/3/):

JS:

```
$(function () {
  $(document).on('change', 'select.products', function(){
    var selected = $(this).val();
    $(this).parents('tr').find('.price').val(selected);
  });
  $(document).on('click', '.addProduct', function(){
    var ele = $(this).parents('tr').clone();
    ele.find('input[type=text]').val('');
    $(this).parents('tr').after(ele);
  });
  $(document).on('click', '.delProduct', function(){
    if($(this).parents('table').find('tr').length > 2) {
      $(this).parents('tr').remove();
    }
  });
});
```

Also I've updated your HTML:

```
<td><input size=25 type="text" class="lngbox" readonly=true/></td> 
<td><input size=25 type="text" class="price" readonly=true/></td>
<td><input type="button" class="delProduct" value="Delete" /></td>
<td><input type="button" class="addProduct" value="AddMore" /></td>
```

Comment: Good progress Huelfe but the the onchange function has effect on the first row input element with id price..Its effect should be on each corresponding input element that has been added..please you just need to adjust the code a little bit thanks i appreciate

Comment: I found the fix . I just changed attribute from id to class  and it works....Thanks Huelfe

Comment: but there is a small bug , the onchange function has effect on  all the input elements value with class price that have been added..

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$("select.products").on("change", function(){
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();

    var td = $(this).parent();
    (((td).parent()).children()[2].getElementsByTagName("input")[0]).value = selectedValue;
});
```